# Button is not responding on its click event?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, button, webforms

I have dragged a button and coded on its click event but it is not responding.
I have inserted breakpoints but with no effect on button click. Nothing happens on clicking the button.
My code is

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AnonymousMaster.master.cs" Inherits="anonymous_AnonymousMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE 6]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/png-fix.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Attach our CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css"/>  

        <!-- Attach necessary scripts -->
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family: "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica-Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; }
            .big-link { display:block; margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 70px; color: #06f; }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">



        /*------------------------------*/

        #signup {
            width: 480px;
            height: auto;
            margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
            background: #fff url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAAECAMAAAB883U1AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAAlQTFRF7+/v7u7u////REBVnAAAAAN0Uk5T//8A18oNQQAAABZJREFUeNpiYGJiYmBiYgRiBhAGCDAAALsAFJhiJ+UAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
            border-radius: 3px;  
        }

        #signup::before, 
        #signup::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -3px;
            left: 2px;
            right: 2px;
            top: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;         
        }

        #signup::after {
            left: 4px;
            right: 4px;
            bottom: -5px;
            z-index: -2;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        }

        /*------------------------------*/

        #signup h1 {
            position: relative;
            font: italic 1em/3.5em 'trebuchet MS',Arial, Helvetica;
            color: #fff;
            background-color:#7cbfff;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 0 20px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) inset;
        }

        #signup h1::before,
        #signup h1::after{
            content:'';
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
            top: 10px;
            bottom: 10px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        #signup h1::after{
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 10px;
            right: 10px;
        }

        /*------------------------------*/

        ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
           color: #bbb;
        }

        :-moz-placeholder {
           color: #bbb;
        }                       

        .placeholder{
            color: #bbb; /* polyfill */
        }       

        #signup input{
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            *width: 518px;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px; 
        }
            #signup select{
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            *width: 518px;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px; 
        }


        #signup input:focus{
            outline: 0;
            border-color: #aaa;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
        }   
        #signup select:focus{
            outline: 0;
            border-color: #aaa;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
        }       

        #signup button , #signup input[type=submit]{
            margin: 20px 0 0 0;
            padding: 15px 8px;          
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid #2493FF;
            overflow: visible;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #fff;
            font: bold 1.4em arial, helvetica;
            text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);         
            background-color: #2493ff;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,.5)), to(rgba(255,255,255,0)));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,0));
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,0));
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,0));
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,0));
            background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,0));
            -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: background-color .2s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: background-color .2s ease-out; 
            -o-transition: background-color .2s ease-out;  
            transition: background-color .2s ease-out;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-box-shadow:  0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),
                              0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),
                                0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),
                        0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;                                    
        }

        #signup button , #signup input[type=submit]:hover{
            background-color: #7cbfff;
            border-color: #7cbfff;
        }

        #signup button , #signup input[type=submit]:active{
            position: relative;
            top: 3px;
            text-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) inset;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) inset;
        }

        /* ------------------------------------------------- */

        #about{
            color: #999;
            text-align: center;
            font: 0.9em Arial, Helvetica;
        }

        #about a{
            color: #777;
        }       
    </style>
    <script language="javascript">
        function test() {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header" class="shell">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1>
                    <a href="#">BestSeller</a></h1>
                <span><a href="#">free css template</a></span>
            </div>
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Navigation -->
            <div class="cl">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <!-- Login-details -->
            <div id="login-details">
                <p>
                    <a href="#" id="A1" data-reveal-id="myModal">Login  </a> ..</p>
                <p>
                <p>
                    Welcome, <a href="#" id="user">Guest</a> .</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="cart">
                        <img src="css/images/cart-icon.png" alt="" /></a>Shopping Cart (0) <a href="#" class="sum">
                            $0.00</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- End Login-details -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Header -->

        <!-- Slider -->
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="shell">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="css/images/so0.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="details">
                            <h2>
                                ClickDesire</h2>
                            <h3>
                                Special Offers</h3>
                            <p class="title">
                                Get Upto 50% Discount on Purchase worth Rs. 1999. or More</p>
                            <p class="description">
                                This Season Purchase any Desired Shoes and Save upto 50%</p>
                            <a href="#" class="read-more-btn">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="css/images/so1.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="details">
                            <h2>
                                ClickDesire
                            </h2>
                            <h3>
                                Special Offers</h3>
                            <p class="title">
                                Flat 50% off + Extxa 10% on Purchase of Formal Wear</p>
                            <p class="description">
                                This Season ClickDesire brought an exciting offer<br />
                                On Purchase of any <b>Men</b> or<b>Women</b> Formal Wear<br />
                                Get 10% extra Discount</p>
                            <a href="#" class="read-more-btn">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="css/images/so2.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="details">
                            <h2>
                                ClickDesire
                            </h2>
                            <h3>
                                Special Offers</h3>
                            <p class="title">
                                Buy 1 Get 1 Free</p>
                            <p class="description">
                                Buy any Bed Sheet and get 50% on 2nd BedSheet</p>
                            <a href="#" class="read-more-btn">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="css/images/so3.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="details">
                            <h2>
                                ClickDesire
                            </h2>
                            <h3>
                                Special Offers</h3>
                            <p class="title">
                                Buy a Combo of Western Girl Dress at the Price of one</p>
                            <p class="description">
                                Buy Two similar westren Dresses at the price of Single Dress
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="read-more-btn">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="css/images/so4.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="details">
                            <h2>
                                ClickDesire
                            </h2>
                            <h3>
                                Special Offers</h3>
                            <p class="title">
                                Sale!! Sale!! Sale!!</p>
                            <p class="description">
                                All Casual Wear From just Rs.500</p>
                            <a href="#" class="read-more-btn">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="css/images/so5.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="details">
                            <h2>
                                ClickDesire
                            </h2>
                            <h3>
                                Special Offers</h3>
                            <p class="title">
                                Buy a Combo of Mens T-Shirts at the Price of one</p>
                            <p class="description">
                                Buy Two similar T-Shirts at the price of Single T-Shirt
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="read-more-btn">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="nav">
                    <a href="#">1</a> <a href="#">2</a> <a href="#">3</a> <a href="#">4</a> <a href="#">
                        5</a> <a href="#">6</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Slider -->
        <!-- Main -->
        <div id="main" class="shell">
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar">
                <ul class="categories">
                    <li>
                        <div id='cssmenu'>
                            <h4>
                                Categories</h4>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="repcategory" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repcategory_ItemDataBound">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ul>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" Value='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>' runat="server" />
                                    <li class="active has-sub"><a href='#'><span>
                                        <%#Eval("CategoryName") %></span></a>
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="repsubcategory" OnItemDataBound="repsubcategory_ItemDataBound"
                                            runat="server">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <ul>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf2" Value='<%# Eval("SubCategoryID") %>' runat="server" />
                                                <li class="has-sub"><a href='#'><span>
                                                    <%#Eval("SubCategoryName") %></span></a>
                                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repsubcategory2" OnItemDataBound="repsubcategory2_ItemDataBound"
                                                        runat="server">
                                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                                            <ul>
                                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hf3" Value='<%# Eval("SubCategory2ID") %>' runat="server" />
                                                            <li><a href='AnonymousProductSubCategory2.aspx?SubCategory2ID=<%# Eval("SubCategory2ID") %>'>
                                                                <span>
                                                                    <%#Eval("SubCategory2Name") %></span></a> </li>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                                </li>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                </ul></FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </ul></FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4>
                            Authors</h4>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="repcompany" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <%--  <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperCompany" runat="server"><%#Eval("CompanyName") %></asp:HyperLink>--%>
                                    <a href='AnonymousCompanyProduct.aspx?CompanyID=<%# Eval("CompanyID") %>'><span>
                                        <%#Eval("CompanyName")%></span></a> </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </ul></FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Sidebar -->
            <!-- Content -->
            <div id="content">
                <!-- Products -->
                <div class="products">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    <!-- End Products -->
                </div>

            <!-- End Content -->
            <div class="cl">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Main -->
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer" class="shell">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="cnt">
                    <div class="col about">
                        <h4>
                            About clickDesire.com</h4>
                        <p>
                            It's nice of you to take the time to get to know us better. Here are some things
                            about us that we thought you might like to know.
                            <br />
                            ClickDesire was developed in 2013 as a Project to be submitted in College.We're
                            present across various categories including healthcare and personal products,apparels,
                            shoes – and still counting!
                            <br />
                            Be it our path-breaking services like Cash on Delivery, a 30-day replacement policy,
                            EMI options, free shipping - and of course the great prices that we offer, everything
                            we do revolves around our obsession with providing our customers a memorable online
                            shopping experience. Then there's our dedicated ClickDesire delivery partners who
                            work round the clock to personally make sure the packages reach on time.
                            <br />
                            So it's no surprise that we're a favourite online shopping destination.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col store">
                        <h4>
                            Store</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Special Offers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Basket</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col" id="newsletter">
                        <h4>
                            Newsletter</h4>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
                        </p>
                        <form action="" method="post">
                        <input type="text" class="field" value="Your Name" title="Your Name" />
                        <input type="text" class="field" value="Email" title="Email" />
                        <div class="form-buttons">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn" />
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cl">
                        &nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="copy">
                        <p>
                            &copy; <a href="#">BestSeller.com</a>. Design by <a href="http://css-free-templates.com/">
                                CSS-FREE-TEMPLATES.COM</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Footer -->
    </div>
     <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">

         <div id=signup>   
                <h1>
                    <b>Signin</b></h1>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" placeholder="Choose Your UserName" required="" runat="server"
                     ValidationGroup="vg2"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requser" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtusername"
                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter UserName" ValidationGroup="vg2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" placeholder="Choose your password" required="" runat="server"
                    TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="vg2"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqpassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtpassword"
                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter Password" ValidationGroup="vg2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg2" OnClick="Login_Click"  Text="SignIn" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="signuplink" runat="server" OnClick="LinkLoginClick" >Register Now</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:Label ID="lblloginmsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <!-- End Products -->
          </div>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and for click event of button

```
 protected void LoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         string userName = txtusername.Text.Trim().ToString();
         LoginInfo login = new DBAction.Login().GetLoginData(userName);
         if (login != null)
         {

                Session["UserName"] = txtusername.Text.Trim().ToString();
                lblloginmsg.Text = "Login In Process";
                Response.Redirect("./client/ClientHome.aspx");
            }
            else if (login == null)
            {
                lblloginmsg.Text="UserName or password is incorrect";
            }
         }


    }
```

The div is called at its master pages by just giving div id
Whats the problem please help

Comment: Does the page reload or is really nothing happening?

Comment: did you put a breakpoint in it?

Comment: I would show a message with your label in the if(login != null) to see if that part of code is actually being called. If they label shows, then the click is working.

Comment: Friend it responds for validator but not for coding.When i click it, its ask to enter the username and password but afterward not does anything

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code in a new ASP.NET Web Forms Application I've just created. The code works just fine and I'm coming to the button code as well. You haven't pasted all your code above so I've pasted it all down here and you can see if anything is missing in your code. This, that I've pasted here, works just fine on my computer (Visual Studio 2012 and .Net 4.5)

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
  <section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
            <h2>Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET application.</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <p>
            To learn more about ASP.NET, visit <a href="http://asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">http://asp.net</a>.
            The page features <mark>videos, tutorials, and samples</mark> to help you get the most from ASP.NET.
            If you have any questions about ASP.NET visit
            <a href="http://forums.asp.net/18.aspx" title="ASP.NET Forum">our forums</a>.
        </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <p>  
        <div id="signup">
            <h1>
                <b>Signin</b></h1>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" placeholder="Choose Your UserName" required="" runat="server"
                onclick="this.value='';" onblur="this.value"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requser" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtusername"
                ErrorMessage="Please Enter UserName" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" placeholder="Choose your password" required="" runat="server"
                TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqpassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtpassword"
                ErrorMessage="Please Enter Password" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" OnClick="LoginClick" ValidationGroup="vg1" Text="SignIn" /><br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="signuplink" runat="server" OnClick="LinkLoginClick" >Register Now</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:Label ID="lblloginmsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <!-- End Products -->
        </div></p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The code for the button is almost the same. My Visual Studio wanted it to be `Public` instead of `Protected`. You can try to make that change as well.

```
public void LoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Popup? Is the code in a popup-window? You probably need to tell us more about your code because when I just paste your code into a new ASP.NET application then it all works just fine. So there must be something else that is the problem, something you're not showing us in the code above. You can paste in ALL the code from your browser when you open the page, that would probably be very helpful. Or, all the code from the `.aspx` file. If you don't give us more code then I can't help you.

Comment: Sir so should i post all the css and jquery file and master page

Comment: You don't need to post css and jquery. But your master page and the complete code of your main page (the page that has the button). Then I can look more into it.